# How can I give users access to MySQL database securely without showing them my database credentials

Tags: php, mysql

Customers download front end source code from my website which contains database access on my server.
I don't want to incldue the config.php file in the download so have used:

```
<?php include("http://www.othersite.com/config.php"); ?>
```

Is there a more secure or more efficient way (as users have to enable allow_remote_url in their php.ini currently) of providing users access?

Answer (score 2):

How about creating users in mysql for each customer, then give them access to one database only? Or provide an api which can access the database?

Comment: I would like it to be dynamic so I do not have to get involved. The api may be a good option